# Can you make it so, when your phone connects to the Hc-05 on a Arduino, a variable changes?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05, android

So whenever my phone gets close, and it connects to the Hc-05, the Arduino changes a variable? I want to avoid the use of apps, where the user has to do anything after first time connecting. The project is an automatic door opener, wherein the user for whatever reason can't use their hands, like if they have groceries in their hands.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Detecting successful connection with HC-05

The HC-05 can be configured to do what you are after.

Search for "POLAR" in the [AT set documentation](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/HC-0305%20serail%20module%20AT%20commamd%20set%20201104%20revised.pdf).

```
AT+POLAR=0,1
```

should be what you need as per their examples.
Hook up **PI09** to your arduino and wait for it to go HIGH.
You may even want to wake up your arduino with an hardware interrupt using that signal.

Depending on your package, this may require soldering to the HC-05 module.
The [datasheet](https://cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2014/03/hc_hc-05-user-instructions-bluetooth.pdf) features a pinout in that case. Be sure to checkout the manual of your breakout board first.